# How to get the first cell value of a hierarchy telerk grid view when user selectes a record

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using *telerik grid view* and i want to get the first element
when user selects a **child's row** (there migh be some recordes or rows)

I have this but it get's the first one anyway

```
radGridView1.Rows[0].ChildRows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

How can i get the first cell that user selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user selects a row in RadGridView - no matter if it is master or child row, this row can be accessed via the CurrentRow property:

```
radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value
```

You can also check out this article: [link](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/rows/selected-rows-and-current-row)